# Using TempData inside ASP.NET SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, signalr

Is it possible to change ASP.NET MVC TempData in ControllerBase (TempDataDictionary) inside a SignalR Hub?

```
public TestHub : Hub
{
    public bool? IsRunning
    {
        get 
        {
            return Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Application["IsRunning"] as bool?;
        }
        set { Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Application["IsRunning"] = value; }
    }
}
```

I know I can access Session and Application variables, but is it possible to access controller variables?